# How can I embed a controller in my template only if an event occurs?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have a button in my template defined like:

```
<input type="button" value="Button"
       onclick="callController('someValue')"/>
```

and a javascript block defined earlier:

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
    function callController(value)
    {
        //Code to call the controller here, passing value
    }
</script>
```

I tried doing it with

```
{% render "Stuff:Stuff:action" with {'value' = value } %}
```

, but that line is evaluated when entering the page instead off when I click the button, and it complains that value isn't defined (cause it is only defined after clicking the button).
I also tried with

```
window.location.href = "{{ path('routeToPage', {'value' = value}) }}"
```

but it also evaluated before the variable is defined,so I get an error.

Can I make it so that this twig line is executed after I click the button, which is what I want? Or should I take another approach? How could I execute that action without using twig?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Stuff:Stuff:action` has no @Route annotation you need to write a wrapper action in whose template you would render that `Stuff:Stuff:action`. However, if "action" from `Stuff` Controller **does** have @Route it's even simpler.

Anyways, AJAX comes to my mind:

Here I used jQuery but you're free to use library of your choice (or none whatsoever):

```
<input id="controllerLoader" type="button" value="Button" />

$(function(){
    $('#controllerLoader').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('wrapperRoute')}}', // or direct call if there is a `@Route`
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(responseHtml){
                $('#controller_embed_position').html(responseHtml);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

The rest is only needed when there is no `@Route` annotation defined in `Stuff:Stuff:action`.

You would need a dummy controller action:

```
/**
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle::dummy.html.twig");
 * @Route("/dummy", name="wrapperRoute");
 */
public function dummyAction(){
    return array();
}
```

and finally, dummy.html.twig:

```
{% render "Stuff:Stuff:action" with {'value' = value } %}
```

Hope I didn't miss something...

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but it isn't working when I click the button. At least it isn't loading the controller with the page either.
By the way, I have a routing yml file with this route, which I guess it's the same as adding the @Route anotation

Comment: hello julkson , I think your controller redirect to some page when calling your controller right? When calling a controller via Ajax,it cannot redirect a page.